# MassTransit deserialization of sub structure in comsumer C#

Tags: c#, json, masstransit

I am using Masstransit, the problem I am facing is that masstrasit don`t serialize for me a sub structure object.

I am sending MessageRequest object with the following properties:

```
public class MessageRequest
{

public MessageRequest(string requestId, string methodToExecute, List<KeyValuePair<string, object>> methodParams)
{
    RequestId = requestId;
    MethodToExecute = methodToExecute;
    MethodParams = methodParams;
}

public string RequestId { get; set; }

public string MethodToExecute { get; set; }

public List<KeyValuePair<string, object>> MethodParams { get; set; }
}
```

Creating the MessageRequest in the Sender:

```
    var mailObject = new MailObject
    {
        From = "from",
        To = "to",
        Subject = "subject",
        Body = "body"
    };

    var parameters = new List<KeyValuePair<string, object>>
    {
        new KeyValuePair<string, object>("mailObject", mailObject)
    };

    MessageRequest messageRequest =
        new MessageRequest("1", "ReceiveMailObject", parameters);
```

Consumer class signature:

```
RequestConsumer : IConsumer<MessageRequest>
```

In the reciever however, the MailObject that I am sending is in a json format and not in MailObject as I would like it to be.

I tried to use     `[Serializable]` and `[DataMember]` attributes in my MailObject and still the same.

Any ideas what to do in order to fix the problem?

P.S, I don't want to use `Json.Deserialization` function because I need this code to be Generic as possible in order to use reflection

Comment: You left out the `MessageRequest` class def, which is the most important thing to answer you question.

Comment: @ChrisPatterson added the class def